# Override onDraw() or draw()?

Tags: android, draw, surfaceview, ondraw

My project is based on surfaceView and up until now I've had all of my rendering in onDraw which I am overriding.  All seemed to be OK.

However, I've just updated my SDK and now it gives me an error telling me:

> Suspicious method call; should probably call "draw" rather than "onDraw"

Could someone please explain the difference between these two?

I've read some similar questions around the net but I've not found an explanation that I understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[SurfaceView.draw()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/SurfaceView.java#SurfaceView) basically calls [View.draw();](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) If you want to implement your drawing, you should do it in [View.onDraw()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.onDraw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) which is for you to implement which even says in the source code comments.

> This method is called by ViewGroup.drawChild() to have each child view
>   draw itself. This draw() method is an implementation detail and is not
>   intended to be overridden or to be called from anywhere else other
>   than ViewGroup.drawChild().

As for difference between them:
draw():

```
13416        /*
13417         * Draw traversal performs several drawing steps which must be executed
13418         * in the appropriate order:
13419         *
13420         *      1. Draw the background
13421         *      2. If necessary, save the canvas' layers to prepare for fading
13422         *      3. Draw view's content
13423         *      4. Draw children
13424         *      5. If necessary, draw the fading edges and restore layers
13425         *      6. Draw decorations (scrollbars for instance)
13426         */
```

onDraw() is empty. Its for you to implement.

Comment: Is it just an incorrect assumption by the SDK then that it's telling me I should 'probably' be calling draw()?

Comment: Based on documents, you should 'probably' not be calling draw() but it may really depend on what your actual code is.

Answer (score 22):

I tried cleaning my project and it did solve the problem. Try it.

Comment: It doesn't "solve" it, it just clears it. It's a lint error and by default the lint is run on modified files. When the lint is re-run, the same lint error will reappear.

Comment: This should be set as the correct answer. It seems to be an Eclipse bug.

Answer (score 7):

I have the problem since ever.

I handle it like this:

1) Declare a method like the following.

```
@SuppressLint("WrongCall")
public void drawTheView() {
    theCanvas = null;

    try{
        theCanvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
        if(theCanvas != null) {
            onDraw(theCanvas);
        }
    } finally {
        getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(theCanvas);
    }
}
```

2) Now you can modify the onDraw() Method:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //Do some drawing


}
```

You can call the drawTheView() method from everywhere you want and call the onDraw() method this way without getting the error...

I think this is a practical way.

Comment: You may need to add `import android.annotation.SuppressLint;` at the beginning of the file, it took me a while before figuring out why I get a `cannot find symbol` error.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the case of drawing, overriding **draw()** and calling **super.draw** is often used when a ViewGroup wants to draw content over its child views. Content drawn in **onDraw** will appear under children.﻿

Answer (score 2):

As friiky said, `@SuppressLint("WrongCall")` fixed my problem. However it must be in front of the method name, not the above.

What I did is put mouse over the error code, right click and select `Add @SuppressLint("WrongCall")`

Comment: It seems to work and everything, but I'm not very happy about adding a 'suppress error'. Just waiting for the day it backfires..

Answer (score -3):

`onDraw` gives you a canvas to draw to the screen.

`draw()` allows you to manually draw a canvas to the screen (you have to make the canvas yourself).